# In Chrome-Extension getting CORB error on injecting external script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am creating a Chrome-extension and I want to inject a Javascript file in DOM from content.js file , But after injecting JS file I am getting `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avinashiitb/bookmark-preview/main/injectScript.js`

The idea behind to inject `injectScript.js` is to write a custom event in DOM and pass that event to `content.js` script

Manifest.Json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Preview & Bookmark",
   "author": "Aviansh",
   "version": "0.001",
   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "matches": ["*://*/*"],
           "js": [
               "content.js"
           ],
           "css": [
               "style.css"
           ]
       }
   ],
   "background": {
       "scripts": [
           "background.js"
       ]
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       "inject-script.js"
   ],
   "browser_action": {},
   "permissions": [
       "storage",
       "*://*/*"  
   ]
}
```

Content.js

```
function injectScript(file_path, tag) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    node.appendChild(script);
}

injectScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avinashiitb/bookmark-preview/main/injectScript.js", 'body');
```

injectScript.js

```
alert("Hi");
```

Comment: The question was marked as duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981059/in-chrome-extension-getting-corb-error-on-injecting-external-script. That question was made ten years ago.
Please remove the duplicated label.
CORB's issue with the chrome extension has been far more complicated to fix since a year ago. So answers before a 2021 have no value

Comment: This specific question is an exact duplicate because of the goal for which the script is injected. This is not about general CORB problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the script from the remote URL into your extension directory.
2. Rename it to `inject-script.js`
3. Run it as shown in [method 1 here](/a/9517879):

```js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('inject-script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Comment: This does not work since some years ago. Notice the questions ask how to fix the CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking) issue.
This security was added since Chrome 72.

Comment: It works now just as it always did - to solve the specific goal of injecting in page context. This is not related to general problems with CORB.